# Invert a single column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I do have a DataFrame mxn and would like to flip one column in similar way to list flip e.g.:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = list1[::1]
```

so
list2 looks like this: `[4,3,2,1]`

How to apply something similar to a DataFrame to a column but keep order of all rows and other columns so I flip the values in the single column only:

e.g.

df1 =

```
    col1    col2
1    cat     1
2    dog     2
3    fish    3
4    bird    4
5    mouse   5
```

to df2

```
    col1    col2
1    cat     5
2    dog     4
3    fish    3
4    bird    2
5    mouse   1
```

Comment: `df2 = df1.assign(col2=df1['col2'].iloc[::-1])`

Comment: `df1.assign(col2=df1.col2.loc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True))` actually works. If you don't reset the indices, then you will likely end up with the same dataframe.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be:

```
df.col2 = df.col2.values[::-1]
df

    col1  col2
1    cat     5
2    dog     4
3   fish     3
4   bird     2
5  mouse     1
```

---

Or, using `df.assign` (to return a copy, not as efficient as inplace assignment):

```
df2 = df.assign(col2=df.col2.values[::-1])
df2

    col1  col2
1    cat     5
2    dog     4
3   fish     3
4   bird     2
5  mouse     1
```

Comment: I have used option 1: df.col2 = df.col2.values[::-1] and it works. I guess I do not have to reset the index? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @BlueTomato You certainly don't. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try concating this to your dataframe.

df1['col2'].loc[::-1]

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
>>> df1
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
>>> df1[0]=df1[0].loc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
>>> df1
   0  1  2
0  7  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  1  8  9
```